# Compare datetime with string time in 24 hrs format

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I have a following code:

```
public string startTime = "0900";
public string closeTime = "1730";


public class TimesInfo
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime closeTime { get; set; }
}
```

Sample data:

```
List<TimesInfo> list = new List<TimesInfo>();
list.Add(new TimesInfo { EmpCode = "101", startTime=”2011-04-28 10:00”, closeTime=”2011-04-28 12:00” });
list.Add(new TimesInfo { EmpCode = "102", startTime=”2011-04-28 09:00”, closeTime=”2011-04-28 17:00” });
list.Add(new TimesInfo { EmpCode = "103", startTime=”2011-04-28 10:00”, closeTime=”2011-04-28 18:00” });
list.Add(new TimesInfo { EmpCode = "104", startTime=”2011-04-28 11:00”, closeTime=”2011-04-28 16:00” });
```

I would like to find `List<TimesInfo>` which is between `startTime` and `closeTime`.

So from above list we should be able to retrieve all the employee except code 103 because 18:00 is later than 17:00.

Comment: Makes no sense; in `TimeInfo`, `startTime` and `closeTime` are **typed as `DateTime`** - yet you are giving them string values. Does not compile. Can you fix the question? I don't want to make assumptions about in which direction you need to change it... Also: `EmpCode` vs `Code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first parse the strings to `TimeSpan`

```
TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.ParseExact(startTime, "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan close = TimeSpan.ParseExact(closeTime, "hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

then you can use this LINQ query:

```
List<TimesInfo> inRange = list
 .Where(ti => ti.startTime.TimeOfDay >= start && ti.closeTime.TimeOfDay <= close)
 .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to make `startTime` and `closeTime` (the variables, not the class members) `TimeSpan` objects.  Then you can just compare them to the `TimeOfDay` of the DateTime members:

```
list.Where(ti => ti.startTime.TimeOfDay >= startTime &&
                 ti.closeTime.TimeOfDay <= closeTime)
```